# Debian Jessie UpStart / Systemd / SysV no more reboot

Tags: debian, upstart, systemd, sysv

I have make some test on a Jessie server with Upstart installation and replace it by SysV and the reverse.

After this I'm not anymore able to reboot.

```
root@amoo-001:~# reboot
Failed to talk to init daemon.

root@amoo-001:~# systemctl reboot
Failed to get D-Bus connection: Unknown error -1
```

Comment: Try installing dbus if it complains that dbus is missing

Comment: @ptman dbus was installed and running.

Answer (score 8):

I have manually stopped all my important services like LDAP, PostgreSQL and MySQL. And I did run:

```
reboot -f
```

The `-f` force parameter to ignore the init system. After the reboot I was able to make a simple `reboot` without force mode.

Another solution could be more agressive but useful to know, send a magic sysreq remotely with:

```
echo b > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

See more information about [Magic SysReq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key) on Wikipedia.